# How would I iterate a List of custom objects comparing couples in a list and removing based on a specific conditional?

Tags: java, list, iterator, duplicates, comparison

I'm trying to iterate over a list to compare custom objects of . There are a number of different fields in each record but I want to check each record based on two values "EmpNum" and "GroupNum". If the iteration detects a particular EmpNum and GroupNum i want to ignore any other following Record in the list with the same EmpNum and GroupNum afterwards.

I've tried using a for each loop to iterate through which is good for making comparisons but from what I've been reading you shouldn't remove from a list using a for each loop. That any removal should be done using a iterator class. But when I try nested iterator loops to compare couples I'm not sure how to remove the check.

```java
 ListIterator<Record> iteration1 = uploadRecordList.listIterator()
        if (iteration1.hasNext()){
            for (Record record1 = iteration1.next(); iteration1.hasNext(); 
record1 = iteration1.next()){
                ListIterator<Record> iteration2 = 
uploadRecordList.listIterator(iteration1.nextIndex());
                for (Record record2 = iteration2.next(); 
iteration2.hasNext(); record2 = iteration2.next()){


                System.out.println("---RECORD ONE----")
                System.out.println("record1 ID      "+ record1.id.toString())
                System.out.println("record1 relID = "+ record1.relationshipId.toString())
                System.out.println("record1 empID = "+ record1.employeeId.toString())
                System.out.println("record1 actionIndicator = "+ record1.actionIndicator.toString())
                System.out.println("record1 consultant = "+ record1.consultant)
                System.out.println("-----------------")
                System.out.println("---RECORD TWO----")
                System.out.println("record1 ID      "+ record2.id.toString())
                System.out.println("record2 relID = "+ record2.relationshipId.toString())
                System.out.println("record2 empID = "+ record2.employeeId.toString())
                System.out.println("record2 actionIndicator = "+ record2.actionIndicator.toString())
                System.out.println("record2 consultant = "+ record2.consultant)


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should I create a new list and return it comparing each individual list item against what exists in the new list?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a temporary list and add removed records to it and finally remove temp list from main list.
Else you could use Iterator remove method to avoid ConcurrentModificationException.

Be careful while removing using Iterator remove method, you should remove current object not any object.

Comment: So -- I could iterate through the first list with a nested for each loop? all duplicates I find off each iteration I could add to the temporary list and then do a removalAll from the first list using the temporarylist results after the final iteration?